# Minimizing repetitive code in C++, a not so straightforward case

Tags: c++, dry

I am working on a piece of code that copies a 'Person' object from one data representation to another. The names in each class (name, address, title) match, and all types are strings. For each field I want to apply the same transformation, based on some condition that also depends on the field name. The tricky part is that the repeating code uses function suffixes that are based on the field name.  It looks something like this:

```
LibraryA::Person person1;
LibraryB::Person person2;

if (person1.name_valid() && [...somestuff...]) {
    string *v = SomeOtherFunction(person.name())
    person2.set_name(v);
}
if (person1.address_valid() && [...somestuff...]) {
    string *v = SomeOtherFunction(person.address())
    person2.set_address(v);
}
if (person1.title_valid() && [...somestuff...]) {
    string *v = SomeOtherFunction(person.title())
    person2.set_title(v);
}
```

Is there a trick (or technique :) ) to factor out the repetitive part to a template? I'd prefer a solution that **does not** involve defining a macro (that would be too easy :) )

Comment: At least you have a macro at your disposal.  I've wished for that many times in the more dynamic languages I've worked in.

Comment: Is `[...somestuff...]` the same for each `if` statement?

Comment: @gahooa In those more dynamic languages you can often call methods based on a variable at runtime making this fairly trivial to DRY-up.

Comment: @ildjam, yes, [...somestuff...] is a constant part. I probably should have left it out of the sample, since it can be factored out.

Comment: If there are only 3 fields, that is not so much of a repetition and it might be even better to keep it as is, at least it is easy to understand.

Comment: Where did the `person.address()` variable in the body of the `if` statements come from?  Or should that be `person1.address()`?

Comment: Couldn't agree more with @7vies. All solutions proposed so far (mine included) are overkill IMO.

Comment: How many fields are there, and how likely is it that the body of the `if` branches changes?

Comment: There were 6 fields when I found it, and I wanted to add 11 more (and probably more will come as this software evolves). Although I accepted one possible answer, I decided with my team mate to keep the code as is and increase the amount of repetition in favor of simplicity.

Comment: @thesamet, if there is only a single place where all those fields are listed, it might be fine. Though, when you have to consider all the 6+11 cases in many different places you might want to look for other solutions. By the way, as all of the fields are just strings, introducing get/set wrappers is the source of code duplication in the first place.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: I understand and use those tools all the time.  Python is one of my favorite languages because of how well it exposes the internals of classes, objects, functions, etc...  However, there are times, from time to time, where a `goto` or macro would come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fits your requirements, but whether I would use it or not is a different question. Only if there is a *huge* amount of repetition I would go through this path, and then I would combine it with a macro to simplify the calling code:

```
void test_and_set( Person const & person1, Person & person2, 
                   bool (Person::*test)() const,
                   std::string (Person::*get)() const,
                   void (Person::*set)( std::string const &) )
{
   if ( (person1.*test)() ) {
      (person2.*set)( (person1.*get)() );
   }
}
```

Used as:

```
test_and_set( person1, person2, &Person::valid_name, &Person::get_name, &Person::set_name );
```

And combined with a local macro:

```
#define TEST_AND_SET( p1, p2, field ) \
    test_and_set( (p1), (p2), &Person::valid_##field, &Person::get_##field, &Person::set_##field )

TEST_AND_SET( person1, person2, name );
TEST_AND_SET( person1, person2, title );
#undef TEST_AND_SET
```

Comment: Accepted this one, although there are several answer similar in spirit to this one (like Asaf's).

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointer to member function. For example (I didn't check if this code compiles):

```
typedef bool (LibraryA::Person::Validator)();
typedef string (LibraryA::Person::FieldGetter)();
typedef void (LibraryB::Person::FieldSetter)(string*);

void ApplyField(LibraryA::Person& person1, LibraryB::Person& person2, Validator vl, FieldGetter get, FieldSetter set)
{
    if (person1.vl() && [...somestuff...])
    {
        string* v = SomeOtherFunction(person1.get());
        person2.set(v);
    }
}

ApplyField(person1, person2, &LibraryA::Person::name_valid, &LibraryA::Person::name, &LibraryB::Person::set_name);
ApplyField(person1, person2, &LibraryA::Person::address_valid, &LibraryA::Person::address, &LibraryB::Person::set_address);
ApplyField(person1, person2, &LibraryA::Person::title_valid, &LibraryA::Person::title, &LibraryB::Person::set_title);
```

I don't think templates fit here because all fields are of the same type. 
And I don't really know what you have against macros in this case. You can use a macrot to generate the call to ApplyField() if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Did this quick, certainly not valid C++ but I hope you get the idea:

```
struct MyFunctor
{
    Person *person1, *person2;

    void operator()(void Person::*validator(), string* Person::*getter(), void Person::*setter(string *))
    {
        if (person1->*validator() && [...somestuff...])
        {
            string* v = SomeOtherFunction(person1->*getter());
            person2->*setter(v);
        }
    }
};


// Usage
MyFunctor f = { person1, person2 };

f(&Person::name_valid, &Person::name, &Person::set_name);
f(&Person::address_valid, &Person::address, &Person::set_address);
f(&Person::title_valid, &Person::title, &Person::set_title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of pointer-to-member objects, fill it with the source and destination of the transformation and then apply the transformation to each entry in that array. This could look something like this:

```
  struct trans_info {
      trans_info(bool         (S::*valid)() const,
                 std::string* (S::*get)()const,
                 void         (T::*set)(std::string*)):
        valid_(valid),
        get_(get),
        set_(set)
      {
      }
      bool         (S::*valid_)() const;
      std::string* (S::*get_)() const;
      void         (S::*set_)(std::string*);
  };

  trans_info const info[] = {
    trans_info(&S::name_valid, &S::name, &T::set_name),
    trans_info(&S::address_valid, &S::address, &T::set_address),
    trans_info(&S::title_valid, &S::title, &T::set_title),
    ...
  };

  template <typename T, int Size> T* begin(T (&array)[Size]) { return array; }
  template <typename T, int Size> T* end(T (&array)[Size])   { return array + Size; }

  transform(S const& person1, T& person2)
  {
     for (trans_info const* it(begin(info)), e(end(info)); it != end; ++it)
     {
        if ((person1.*(it->valid_))() && [...somestuff...]) {
            string *v = SomeOtherFunction(person1.*(it->get_))())
            (person2.*(it->set))(v);
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: +1 for this just so that I can claim I gave an upvote to Dietmar Kühl :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the person objects are immutable to you, you are out of luck.

If they are not, factor the information out of the method name by using tag classes `Person::Name`, `Person::Address` and so on, and then re-writing `*_valid` and `*_set` to use function overloading:

```
 bool Person::is_valid( Name, std::string ) {...)
 bool Person::is_valid( Address, std::string ) {...)
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't modify the Person classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointer-to-member arguments to a template.

But I question the use of pointers to strings, that looks like a probable memory leak.